# Is it allowed to access the second row of a 2d array from the first?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

Suppose we have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a[2][3]{{1, 2, 3},
                {4, 5, 6}};
    a[0][4] = -50;
    std::cout << a[1][1] << std::endl; // prints -50
}
```

Is this guaranteed to work or it is undefined behavior?
As long as I know it is guaranteed that `&a[0][2] + 1 == &a[1][0]`, but on the other side `a[0]` is an array itself and the valid indices for it are `0..2`.

Edit: If it is forbidden by the standard, is there any specific reason to be forbidden? The 'duplicate' question does not answer that. I need to know the technical reason behind this. Why would it be worse if it was allowed?

Comment: I believe that a 2D statically-allocated array must be consecutive in memory by definition (i.e., by he language standard). And since its dimensions are known during compilation-time, this operation should therefore be well defined (to do exactly what you're expecting it to).

Comment: No, this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: In C++, it's not enough to get the address of something. It's often important how you *got* that address. One of the big reasons for this is to helps compilers in reasoning about code to perform better optimizations. While it seems like the address you get from `a[0][4]` will always be that of `a[1][1]` doing it that way violates the rules of the language. For example, maybe the compiler could see that nothing every gets written to the elements of `a[1]` after it's initialized (there is no assignment to an element of `a[1]`) and could optimize the code to just `std::cout<<5<<std::endl;`.